# Using Superfish plugin for context menus

Tags: jquery, superfish

Is it possible to use Superfish to create context menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without modifying the Superfish plugin.

There are, however, [plenty of other jQuery context menu plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/context-menu).

Answer (score 0):

Link is dead. I think he means http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/